# jQuery function not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, internet-explorer

I'm fairly new to jQuery so it is possible it's a simple syntax issue.  Trying to update a select dropdowns values when another select dropdown option is picked.  There is an onclick event that triggers this function.  The below works great in Firefox but not in IE.  Debugger does not give any error.  I'm using jQuery instead of $ because I am using Wordpress.

```
function update_sub_category() 
{
jQuery('select[name="CATEGORY_SUB_TYPE"]').find('option').each(function(){
      if(jQuery(this).attr('data_option') != jQuery('select[name="ENTRY_CATEGORY"] option:selected').val()) {
        jQuery(this).hide();
        }
      if(jQuery(this).attr('data_option') == jQuery('select[name="ENTRY_CATEGORY"] option:selected').val()) {
        jQuery(this).show();
        }
    });
};
```

Here's the HTML

```
<tr>
<td>Entry Category</td>
<td><select onchange="update_sub_category()" name="ENTRY_CATEGORY">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value='1'>Filter Option 1</option>
    <option selected='selected' value='2'>Filter Option 2</option>
    <option value='3'>Filter Option 3</option>
    </select>
</td>       
<td class="alignright">Category Sub Type</td>
<td><select name="CATEGORY_SUB_TYPE">
    <option data_option='1' value='1-1'>Option 1-1</option>
    <option data_option='1' value='1-2'>Option 1-2</option>
    <option data_option='2' value='2-1'>Option 2-1</option>
    <option data_option='3' value='3-1'>Option 3-1</option>
    </select>
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You can follow an `if`-statement with an `else`: `if ( condition ) { /*do stuff if true condition*/ } else { /* do stuff if false condition*/ }`

Comment: You can not have onclick in the options, off to find a dupe.

Comment: Ideally you need to tell us what version of IE this is breaking on, and also what version of jQuery you are using.

Comment: Use onchange event of select.

Comment: IE11 and JQuery 1.11.1

Comment: Changed the onclick to be onchange under <select> but still no luck with IE.  Firefox still works good.

Answer (score 1):

I think some versions of IE wont trigger `onclick` on `<option .../>`. Change your code to:

```
<select onChange="update_sub_category()">
  <option value="1">...</option>
  ...
</select>
```

or bind your change event using jQuery:

```
$(myElement).on('change', function() { /* myElement changed */ });
```

Btw:

You can follow an if-statement with an else:

```
if ( condition ) { 
  // do stuff if condition is true
} 
else { 
  // do stuff if condition is false 
}
```

Comment: Even if this doesn't fix the initial problem, it should still be implemented :)